# how to deselect the default selection of text after using textarea.moveCaretPosition(textarea.getText().length());

Tags: java, swing, sockets

i was instructed to make a text editor using socket programming where there is one server and multiple clients.

when any client changes anything in their text editors the text changes should reflect on all the text editors of all clients.

to make this happen i used action listener to send each and every change to the server and then i used moveCaretposition to move the cursor to the end of the text (without it the cursor position resets to the position of the first character) . the problem i'm facing right now is that whenever the cursor goes back to the end of the text the text gets highlighted , and because the changes reflect on all clients including the client who's making the changes, this client basically can't write , because whenever he tries to type anything the text gets overwritten by the new characters he's typing , since the previous was selected

is there anyway to deselect this default selection every time the changes reflect? so that the clients can actually write in their text editors.

i tried grabfocus (), getfocus() ,moveCaretPosition using both getdocument and getText

but still there's something im missing

```
while(true) {
    String NewDatainTextArea = ClientInput.readLine();
    c1.ChangeText(NewDatainTextArea);//c1 is a text editor object
    c1.t.moveCaretPosition(c1.t.getText().length());
    c1.t.grabFocus();
}
```

is there anyway to deselect this default selection every time the changes reflect? so that the clients can actually write in their text editors.

Comment: This `while(true)` does not look healthy

Comment: `and because the changes reflect on all clients including the client who's making the changes,` - I would say that is a problem. The server should not attempt to update the client that made the original change.

Comment: Don't use moveCaretPosition(...). Instead use `setCaretPosition(...)`